# Android registerForContextMenu out of an Activity

Tags: android, contextmenu

I want to use a Context Menu when a user click on a View inside an Adapter. The problem is that the OnClick for each view is inside an class that is not an activity [it's a class that extends BaseAdapter], inside the public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent).

So, when i try to create the context menu or to register with registerForContextMenu  inside this class that only extends BaseAdapter, it is not possible.

So the question is: the onclick is inside this Not Activity class. Is it possible to give to this class a parameters that allows it to start an context menu?

Comment: Problem solved:
Inside the "class that is not an activity" i'm using a AlertDialog. To use it, i'm giving as an parameter the context of the activity that uses this class. So, it is possible to show a list of options to the user into this class that is not an Activity. For this, is necessary to use:

Looper.prepare();       ab.show();      Looper.loop();

to create a handler for a class that is not an activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use a Context Menu when a user click on a View inside an Adapter.

Hopefully not. You could use a context menu when the user long-presses on an item in the `AdapterView`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/Inflation) demonstrating this.

Anything else (e.g., popping up something "when a user click on a View inside an Adapter") should be an `AlertDialog`, as suggested by @coder_For_Life22.

> So, when i try to create the context menu or to register with registerForContextMenu inside this class that only extends BaseAdapter, it is not possible.

You only call `registerForContextMenu()` once, for the `AdapterView`. You do this from `onCreate()` of the activity, after you have called `setContentView()` and therefore created the `AdapterView`.

Anything else should be an `AlertDialog`.

> Is it possible to give to this class a parameters that allows it to start an context menu?

You should not need to "give to this class a parameters that allows it to start an context menu", because you only call `registerForContextMenu()` once, for the `AdapterView`.

Anything else should be an `AlertDialog`. You can add a constructor on your `Adapter` that takes an `Activity` as a parameter, that your `Adapter` holds onto and uses for the `AlertDialog`. Or, if the `Adapter` is an inner class of the `Activity`, just use `MyActivityName.this` to reference the `Activity`.

Comment: Actually, what i have is a GridView with a ButtonAdapter. I do:
adapter = new ButtonAdapter(this.getApplicationContext, 50, 50);
and then in the class that extends BaseAdapter I include images and set the onclick for each one... and i would like this click to open a Context Menu [or a AlertDialog] allowing to do specific operations with this specific image...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a AlertDialog for this..

It would look something like..

```
gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        showOptionsMenu(position);
        return true;
    }

});

public void showOptionsMenu(int position)
{
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("test").setCancelable(true).setItems(R.array.myOptions,
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
                   //take actions here according to what the user has selected
               }
         }
)
.show();
}
```

Comment: I'm in the Faces.class thas has a grid constructed with the BaseAdapter. When i click an image in the grid, it looks the onclicklistener inside the class that extends the BaseAdapter and SHOULD, in the Faces.class, open a menu... so i cannot simply start a new activity...

Comment: But an alert dialog must be inside an Activity right?
There is not another way to give the BaseAdapter class [who has the click listener for each ImageButton] an View or something that allows it to show as dialog interface?

Comment: Try it out. Its a solution i ran apon.